# Neural Network Random Seed Affecting Results

Tags: c#, random, neural-network, time-series, regression

I was playing around with the code from the interesting article on [time-series regression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt826350.aspx) by James McCaffrey ([download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/A/D/DAD03966-EE31-45A5-90D3-2BF1B48C803F/Code_McCaffreyTestRun1017.zip)).

This essentially uses machine learning to generate a prediction and forecast of the given airline data.

This is my graph generated using the code and data from his article. As you can see, everything appears to be working as normal.
[image]

The problem occurs when I attempt to mess with the random variable. He specifically seeds the `System.Random` object with `0` as seen here: `this.rnd = new System.Random(0);` (in the NeuralNetwork constructor). The program only uses the `rnd` variable when it is assigning the initial weights of the network and when it randomizes the order of data to process. The seed should be independent of the data (i.e. the order processed and random weights assigned should not affect the results).

However, observe what happens when I change only the line `this.rnd = new System.Random(0);` to `this.rnd = new System.Random(1);`. Here I've done nothing else except seed the `System.Random` object with `1` instead of `0`. Now look at the results:

[image]

It is still able to learn and predict the data, however, the forecast is completely wrong! Why does changing the seed have such a significant effect on the results? In theory it shouldn't matter which order data is processed or what the starting weights are, as that's the point of the network, to change the bias until it reaches the solution. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: _(Note: I didn't read your referenced information)_ How do you know that _"the forecast is completely wrong!"_?  If you were to do a full ARIMA analysis on the data, including a measure of confidence on forecast, you would likely find that both forecasts are well within the confidence of the model.  I'm assuming you are using the `rnd` variable to generate the noise in your model.  If you always use the same seed, you will always get the same noise.  If you change the seed, the noise will change, and you will see the change in the output - but both forecasts are likely "correct"

Comment: You can see the pattern from the data that each peak is a little higher than the previous. This matches the forecasted data at seed `0`, as well as the image in the article. Also, what ever the random weights were shouldn't have an effect on the data as the neural network adjusts the weights to find a solution. In both cases, it predicts the data with almost 100% accuracy, however the forecast data is completely different. Why is there such a difference when the prediction is the same, and how can I maximize the confidence in order to get the same forecast?

Comment: If you have a single neuron only, prediction accuracy will be poor - so the number of neurons is increased to improve accuracy. If you have *too many* neurons, that is, if model complexity is too high, it is possible to have "overfitting" that yields good training prediction but poor forecasting. A simple test is to reduce the model complexity and retrain to see if you observe the same phenomenon in your reduced-complexity-model result analysis.

Comment: With a seed of `0` and decrease to `2` inputs, the prediction quality suffers and it was not able to create a meaningful forecast. I get similar results for a seed of `1`. When I increase inputs to `25`, prediction accuracy improved but the forecast has a much lower peak. Again, similar results for a seed of `1`. Does this mean the seed of `0` and input size of `5` were just "magic numbers" that happened to fit the data extremely well? How can I find my own "magic numbers" for my data?

Comment: Is the random seed changing both the data and the initial weights? That is, are you using different data for each of the tests?

Comment: No, the data is the same. The `rnd` variable only affects the initial weights and the order used for training.

Answer (score 2):

I may be a little late to the party, but let me contribute.

With any prediction task we need to distinguish between interpolation and extrapolation.
Neural Networks are function approximators and have the capacity to fit training data very well. If they are not overfitted then they will perform well in the interpolation task (that is predicting on data points that are very close to the observed distributions in the training set).
When it comes to extrapolation (prediction outside of the seen distributions of the dataset) their predictions can be more varied and dependent on their initialization. The reason is that there are always weights in a neural network that are not used for prediction within distribution and for the other weights there is stochasticity to where you'll end up during training. These two factors attribute to some randomness to your predictions. The way you can think of it is the following - the more you're outside of the observed training distribution, the more these random factors affect your prediction. So in your case when predicting outside of the observed scope the random seed starts playing a bigger role.

You can see an example of this in the image. Blue and Orange dots represent the train/test data used to train an ensemble of NNs. The Green dots are from the same function but have been 'hidden'. Each line represents the predictions of one of the NNs in this ensemble. You can observe how the lines are very close to each other in the regions they have seen training data and they become more varied when they are outside of them. This variance is possibly what you're experiencing on your side and is a metric of the unsertainty of the prediction. It's important to note though that even with the uncertainty range evaluated this does not mean predictions (or mean of predictions of the ensemble) are close to reality, so this is not a measure of the error or potential error.

[Ensemble NNs extrapolation predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEGvR.png)

Here are two papers for reference:

1. Xu et al., “How Neural Networks Extrapolate: from Feedforward to Graph Neural Networks“, ICLR’21;
2. Madras et al., “Detecting Extrapolation with Local Ensembles”, ICLR’20.